# How is the su command masking/protecting my password from being displayed on screen?

Tags: terminal, password, su

Apologies if this is an abstract question - I'll try to be as specific as possible.

When I'm at the bash shell and switch to a different account via `su - foo`, I'm prompted for a password.  The characters I type at this password prompt are hidden from the screen with no indication of how many characters I'm typing or what they are.  How is bash (or Linux in general) doing this?

Comment: Who says `bash` does this job? Obviously, it is `su` doing this...

Comment: Good point.  I edited the question title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you type is displayed in the terminal because the terminal "echoes" it back. When asking for password, the echoing is turned off. See also `help read` and its `-s` option.

Answer (score 6):

I believed that `su` probably opened `/dev/tty`, changed the terminal driver settings to not echo, and then read from `/dev/tty`'s file descriptor.

To test this belief, I ran `strace -o su.out su -` on my Arch linux laptop. The relevant part of the `strace` output:

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_CONTINUE or TCSETSF, {B38400 opost isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "Password: ", 10)              = 10
read(0, "hahanotthis\n", 511)                = 7
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

I was not 100% wrong. `su` does in fact read from stdin, but it does turn off echoing on stdin using a terminal control `ioctl()`. After I put in the password, `su` turns echoing back on, again with `ioctl()` system call.

I know that some other programs, the `ftp` client in particular, do use `/dev/tty` to read passwords, which means you can't put a password on the command line, or in a "here document", you have to use some shenanigans.